# Executing Stored Procedure with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, repository-pattern

We are currently developing an internal system, using the repository pattern and Entity Framework 5 as our ORM.

We have a bunch of stored procedures in our database that we call. Some of these procedures have similar parameter names. So when we make a call to execute the stored procedure, like so:

```
DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ReturnType>(query, parameters)
```

The resulting enumerable fails on the second call to another procedure with a similar parameter name, saying:

> ArgumentException was unhandled by user code: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

We have tried putting all `SqlParameters` into a collection which we loop through and null out all the items in the collection, but this fails as well....gloriously.

Is there a way to reach and manipulate the Object array in this stack trace?

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Validate(Int32 index, Object value)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.AddRange(Array values)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateStoreCommand(String commandText, **Object[]   parameters**)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, **Object[] parameters**)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, **Object[] parameters**)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery[TElement](String sql, **Object[] parameters**)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQueryAsIEnumerable[TElement](String sql, **Object[] parameters**)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(Type elementType, String sql, **Object[] parameters**)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlNonSetQuery.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: Can you show more of your code and what line the error occurs on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, sort of a work around this issue. The stored proc call is made to instantiate a new DbContext that will be disposed after execution, like so.

```
IEnumerable<ReturnType> Results = null;

using (DbContext NewContext = new PrometheusEntities())
{
    Results = NewContext.Database.SqlQuery<ReturnType>(query, parameters).ToList();    
}    
return Results;
```

I haven't experienced any issues since employing this method.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like that:

```
List<ReturnType> obj = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ReturnType>(query, parameters).ToList();
```

it will bind the variable obj, after that you can call the obj how many times you want without problem with sqlParameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to resolve the issue, the command object in the built in SqlQuery method does not seem to clear the sql parameters, however I have a work around.
you can create your own command based on the current connection - but you will lose the ability to easily map out a return type.

```
public void CallStoredProc(string query, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    //this.Database.Connection (this = DBContext)
    System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd =  this.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = query;

    // add params
    foreach (var item in parameters)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
    }

    // execute query (not differed)
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    // attempt to read rows
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // row level data
        }
    }

    // cleanup
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to make a copy of your parameters collection and each parameter that in rather than reusing the same instances of the parameters? Maybe have a helper method somewhere that automatically duplicates it for you.

Comment: Should this copy be made immediately before executing DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ReturnType>(query, parameters)?

Also another thing that I wish to ask about. Given that the results are passed into an IEnumerable object, whose contents are only populated once the IEnumerable is iterated over, when is the best time to clear the copy that my helper method generates?

Comment: It might be useful to see how you are doing this. Are you just using the same SQLQuery over & over or something? Maybe add some more detail (code?) to original question.

Comment: It's not necessarily the same query being called over and over. 

Part of the application contains a dashboard for sales teams and we call a stored proc that retrieves Campaigns associated to a particular team and the proc accepts a parameter of type int >@TeamID. 

The next proc that gets executed also has a >@TeamID parameter and that's when the error gets coughed up.

Comment: but are you using something like a static collection? I haven't done what you are describing and I can't make explicit recommendations without seeting what your workflow looks like. Clearly something is being re-used that shouldn't be re-used and if I can see waht that is then perhaps I can give a more specific idea. OTOH I could be totally barking up the wrong tree. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Stored Procedure 
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GelUserContactDetails]  
  (  
    @Id INT=0,  
    @UserId int=0  
  )  
 AS  
    BEGIN  
SELECT M.Id AS UserID, M.FirstName as Name,M.Designation,M.CompanyName FROM dbo.Flo_MemberShip M  
WHERE ID=@Id 
END
```

// Creating Stored Procedure that hold result of class MyContacts

```
 public class MyContacts  
   {  
    public int UserID { get; set; }  
    public string Designation { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Organization { get; set; }  
    public string Image { get; set; }  
    public string RequestDate { get; set; }  
    public string IsContact { get; set; }  
   }
```

here I am creating a Entity that`s name is MyContacts. Here the MyContacts properties name must be the same as the returned column of the select statement of the Stored Procedure.

```
using (var context = new FLOEntities())  
 {  
   string query = "sp_GelUserContactDetails @Id,@UserId";  
   SqlParameter Id = new SqlParameter("@Id", selfId);  
   SqlParameter UserId = new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId);  
   obj = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyContacts>(query, Id, UserId).FirstOrDefault();  
 }  
return obj;
```

[click here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/15886/execute-sql-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx)